# how to resolve Unhandled event loop exception

Tags: java, cocoa, jakarta-ee, testng, eclipse-luna

I am using Eclipse Luna Service release 2 (4.4.2) in my mac system. I had installed testng from market place. **When I am trying to run using testng.xml** as Testng suite, I am getting following two errors on error log  window and testng is not getting launched. But if I am running the same at individual class level(without using testng.xml) it is getting triggered properly without issues.

**1- Message from Error.log "Error"- Stack trace:**

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.testng.eclipse.ui.util.ConfigurationHelper.getBooleanAttribute(ConfigurationHelper.java:374)
    at org.testng.eclipse.ui.util.ConfigurationHelper.isPrefixVmArgsFromPom(ConfigurationHelper.java:122)
    at org.testng.eclipse.ui.util.ConfigurationHelper.getVMArgsFromPom(ConfigurationHelper.java:219)
    at org.testng.eclipse.ui.util.ConfigurationHelper.getJvmArgs(ConfigurationHelper.java:180)
    at org.testng.eclipse.util.LaunchUtil.launchSuiteConfiguration(LaunchUtil.java:152)
    at org.testng.eclipse.util.LaunchUtil.launchSuiteConfiguration(LaunchUtil.java:125)
    at org.testng.eclipse.util.LaunchUtil.launchSuiteConfiguration(LaunchUtil.java:113)
    at org.testng.eclipse.launch.TestNGSuiteLaunchShortcut.run(TestNGSuiteLaunchShortcut.java:38)
    at org.testng.eclipse.launch.TestNGSuiteLaunchShortcut.launch(TestNGSuiteLaunchShortcut.java:20)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.launchConfigurations.LaunchShortcutExtension.launch(LaunchShortcutExtension.java:431)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.actions.LaunchShortcutAction.run(LaunchShortcutAction.java:74)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.actions.LaunchShortcutAction.runWithEvent(LaunchShortcutAction.java:123)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(ActionContributionItem.java:595)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.access$2(ActionContributionItem.java:511)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem$5.handleEvent(ActionContributionItem.java:420)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4199)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1467)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1490)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1475)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.notifyListeners(Widget.java:1279)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem$9.handleEvent(ActionContributionItem.java:1293)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4199)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1467)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1490)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1475)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.notifyListeners(Widget.java:1279)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4042)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3669)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1151)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1032)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:636)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:579)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:380)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:235)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:648)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:603)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1465)
```

**Session Data:**

```
java.version=1.8.0_60
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=macosx, ARCH=x86_64, WS=cocoa, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product -keyring /Users/xxxxxxx/.eclipse_keyring -showlocation
Command-line arguments:  -os macosx -ws cocoa -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product -keyring /Users/xxxxxxx/.eclipse_keyring -showlocation
```

**2. Error message from error.log 'Unhandled event loop exception'**

**Exception stack trace:**

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.testng.eclipse.ui.util.ConfigurationHelper.getJvmArgs(ConfigurationHelper.java:188)
    at org.testng.eclipse.util.LaunchUtil.launchSuiteConfiguration(LaunchUtil.java:152)
    at org.testng.eclipse.util.LaunchUtil.launchSuiteConfiguration(LaunchUtil.java:125)
    at org.testng.eclipse.util.LaunchUtil.launchSuiteConfiguration(LaunchUtil.java:113)
    at org.testng.eclipse.launch.TestNGSuiteLaunchShortcut.run(TestNGSuiteLaunchShortcut.java:38)
    at org.testng.eclipse.launch.TestNGSuiteLaunchShortcut.launch(TestNGSuiteLaunchShortcut.java:20)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.launchConfigurations.LaunchShortcutExtension.launch(LaunchShortcutExtension.java:431)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.actions.LaunchShortcutAction.run(LaunchShortcutAction.java:74)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.actions.LaunchShortcutAction.runWithEvent(LaunchShortcutAction.java:123)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(ActionContributionItem.java:595)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.access$2(ActionContributionItem.java:511)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem$5.handleEvent(ActionContributionItem.java:420)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4199)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1467)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1490)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1475)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.notifyListeners(Widget.java:1279)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem$9.handleEvent(ActionContributionItem.java:1293)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4199)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1467)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1490)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1475)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.notifyListeners(Widget.java:1279)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4042)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3669)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1151)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1032)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:636)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:579)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:380)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:235)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:648)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:603)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1465)
```

**Session Data:**

```
eclipse.buildId=4.4.2.M20150204-1700
java.version=1.8.0_60
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=macosx, ARCH=x86_64, WS=cocoa, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product -keyring /Users/xxxxxxxx/.eclipse_keyring -showlocation
Command-line arguments:  -os macosx -ws cocoa -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product -keyring /Users/xxxxxxxx/.eclipse_keyring -showlocation
```

**I had already tried following options:**

- UnZip eclipse Newly,Install Testng from market place- Then also observed same issue.
- UnInstall and Reinstalled Java 1.8.0.60,Unzipped eclipse,created New Workspace and and Installed TestNg from market place - Then also observed same issue.

Could someone suggest is there any other work around or solution to fix this issue or is it a bug in Eclipse Luna?
Thanks in Advance for your help and support.

Answer (score 0):

I found the workaround Now for launching my TestNG suite by performing following steps.

**Steps:**
Right click on the testng.xml -> Select Run as-> Select Run Configurations-> Double Click TestNg Option-> Browse Suite and select your same testng.xml suite file from the list. Now click Run button and finally my testng.xml suite is getting launched and started running successfully with out issues. This workaround solves my problem.

But still if I am seeing the same reported error(on above question) if I am doing right click on same testng.xml->run as-> TestNg Suite. Not sure why testng suite is not getting launch when I am doing directly, but the same is working fine, when I am running via Run Configurations.